# Parse multiple links using python multi threading pool API

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using python multithreading pool API/function that is:

```
p = multithreading.pool( NO.OF REQUESTS AT A TIME ) 
p.map ( function , iterator )
```

According to my research, the parameter inside the pool function tells us "how many requests do you want to parse at a time ".
So I want to know the exact meaning/explanation of that one parameter "NO.OF REQUESTS AT A TIME" , remember this meaning is according to my research, it may be wrong.

Actually, I have 1500 URLs and I want to parse/extract the info in really less time because using a normal approach it is taking too much time.

I tried with 0-50 parse/request at a time and it worked really well but when I try to do a little bit higher, it won't give me as fast result.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def prices_models_location(i):

    prices = []
    models = []
    location = []
    req = requests.get(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'price'})
    model = soup.find('h2', {'itemprop': 'model'})
    loc = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'availableAtOrFrom'})

    return (prics, loc, model)
p = pool.Pool(50)
Price_location_model = [p.map(prices_models_location, user_sec[0])]

# p.terminate()
# p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj for proper formatting :)
It would be great if you explain the question

Comment: The lowest overhead can be achieved via an async solution. Python 3 supports asynchronous programming very well. e.g. see [this](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)

Comment: @pynchia it would be great if you explain to me about the parameter of pool function and thanks for sharing the blog post :)

Comment: Isn't is obvious?  If you have 100 things to process and you set the parameter to 10, the pool will make sure there are no more than 10 subprocesses running at once.  When one exits, it launches another.  Also remember that you do not have infinite network bandwidth. If you exceed your network bandwidth, the processes will collide with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading is not a magic bullet.

As you are using `requests.get`, your task is IO-bounded by your network bandwidth, so using threads is indeed a correct approach.

Here, what you call *NO.OF REQUESTS AT A TIME* is the number of concurrent threads in the pool. So each thread will spend some time waiting for network data, and other threads will be able to do actual processing during that time. Then it will process the received data, and Python only allows one active thread at a time.

But a thread is a rather complex object that uses a quantity of resources, and Python has to provide synchronization between all those threads. And that synchronization and resource usage comes with some overhead. If you ask more threads that what is *reasonable*, you will lose more time in that overhead than what you gain by having concurrent threads, each running while the others are waiting for network data.

For problems like that, the ideal number of threads is generally in the magnitude order of 10 (greater than 1 less than 100) and experimentation is a correct way to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically has two parts that run in sequence.

1. Get data from the internet using `requests`.
2. Process the retrieved data locally using `BeautifulSoup`.

*Probably*, #1 takes longer than #2.
However, there is more to this question than meets the eye.

You will have to profile the code to know how long each part takes. Normally I would recommend `cProfile` for this. But in this case the significant overhead of profiling would influence `requests` differently than `BeautifulSoup`.

Use `time.monotonic` to ascertain how long things take:

```
def prices_models_location(i):

    prices = []
    models = []
    location = []
    start = time.monotonic()
    req = requests.get(i)
    end = time.monotonic()
    req_time = end - start
    start = time.monotonic()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'price'})
    model = soup.find('h2', {'itemprop': 'model'})
    loc = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'availableAtOrFrom'})
    end = time.monotonic()
    soup_time = end - start
    return (prics, loc, model, req_time, soup_time)
```

Note that it might be better to comment out the `BeautifulSoup` code when getting the timing data for `requests`.

Then analyse the time data.
**Without the timing information from profiling, optimization is no more than guesswork.**

In CPython, for technical reasons, only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. This is enforced by the Global Interpreter Lock ("GIL").

The GIL is released when I/O is performed.
So while `requests.get` is busy, another thread might run `BeautifulSoup`.

You are using `BeautifulSoup` with Python's built-in HTML parser. That means it uses mainly pure python code which *is* subject to the GIL.
So once data is retrieved, it will be *effectively* be processed sequentially even when you are using threads.
Once you are running enough threads to saturate the network connection, `BeautifulSoup` will become the bottleneck.

So it *might* be better to use a `multiprocessing.Pool` instead.
This will make sure that the `BeautifulSoup` part *can* run in parallel. Personally, I tend to use `multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered` because it starts yielding results as soon as they become available.

On the other hand, using a `Pool` with much more processes than your CPU has cores is not as useful as you might think. It would lead to processes from the `Pool` fighting for CPU time.

This is why you need profiling/timing data to make an accurate choice.